# Error when referencing dictionary value in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to display circles by accessing the values for the radius by referencing a dictionary. I can already do it when my vaues are in an array buw when I represent them as a dictionary I get a syntax error, even though d.keyName seems to be the recommended way to do it.

Section of code that works

```
%%javascript
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: 'https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min'
    }
});

(function(element) {
    require(['d3'], function(d3) {   
        var data = [4, 8, 4]
        var svg = d3.select(element.get(0)).append('svg')
            .attr('width', 400)
            .attr('height', 200);

        svg.selectAll('circle')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .style('fill', 'orange')
            .attr("r", function(d) {return 2*d;})
            .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return 30 * (i + 1);})
            .attr("cy", function(d, i) {return 100 + 30 * (i % 3 - 1);})

        ;
    })
})(element);
```

And this is what doesn't work:

```
%%javascript
require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: 'https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min'
    }
});


(function(element) {
    require(['d3'], function(d3) {   
        //var data = [4, 8, 4]
        //var words = ["milk", "but", "hey"]
        var data = [{'num': 4, 'word': 'milk'}, {'num': 8, 'word': 'but'}, {'num': 4, 'word': 'hey'}];

        var svg = d3.select(element.get(0)).append('svg')
            .attr('width', 400)
            .attr('height', 200);

        svg.selectAll('circle')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .style('fill', 'orange')
            .attr("r", function(d.num) {return 2*d.num; })
            .attr("cx", function(d.num, i) {return 30 * (i + 1); })
            .attr("cy", function(d.num, i) {return 100 + 30 * (i % 3 - 1); })
            //.attr("r", function(d) {return 2*d;})
            //.attr("cx", function(d, i) {return 30 * (i + 1);})
            //.attr("cy", function(d, i) {return 100 + 30 * (i % 3 - 1);})



        ;
    })
})(element);
```

Javascript error adding output!
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
See your browser Javascript console for more details.

```
2outputarea.js:764 SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at OutputArea.append_javascript (outputarea.js:762)
    at OutputArea.append_mime_type (outputarea.js:696)
    at OutputArea.append_display_data (outputarea.js:659)
    at OutputArea.append_output (outputarea.js:346)
    at OutputArea.handle_output (outputarea.js:257)
    at output (codecell.js:395)
    at Kernel._handle_output_message (kernel.js:1196)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Kernel._handle_iopub_message (kernel.js:1223)
    at Kernel._finish_ws_message (kernel.js:1015)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error. Because you want to pass `object.property` as parameter to attribute callback
`function(d.num) {return 2*d.num; }`

Use `function(d) {return 2*d.num; }`.

`d` is your current datum in array (or data[i])

Check this [information](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) and how [d3 selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) works